# Available Analysis and Transform passes for LLVM

Tags: llvm

Is there any document on the list of Analysis and Transform passes available for use in the `AnalysisUsage::addRequired<>` and `Pass::geAnalysis<>` functions?

I can get a list of passes in http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html, but it only shows the command line names for the passes. How can I know the underlying pass classes?

Comment: There is this, interestingly: http://www.amazon.com/Getting-Started-LLVM-Core-Libraries/dp/1782166920/

Comment: (http://books.google.ru/books?id=tXZdBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false seems to offer viewing most or even all of the text at the moment)

Comment: Glad to hear, Eli below was actually a reviewer for the book, btw :)

Answer (score 1):

Not really, no. Just look at the source. The header files in `include/llvm/Analysis/` and `include/llvm/Transforms/` will tell you everything you need to know.

Moreover, grepping over the source for `getAnalysis<` will tell you which passes are used as analyses inside the LLVM source code.

Comment: Thanks. I find that the [doxygen](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Pass.html) for `Pass` class gives a list of `Pass`es inheriting `Pass`, which is a good start. Also according to this [post](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.llvm.devel/35640), transform passes shouldn't be depended on. But you can use opt cmd by providing the pass names in proper order.